# Apache Felix Web Console does not find image with absolute path

Tags: java, html, osgi, apache-felix

In order to add my own branding to the [Apache Felix Web Console](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-web-console.html), I registered a [BrandingPlugin](http://felix.apache.org/apidocs/webconsole/4.2.0/org/apache/felix/webconsole/BrandingPlugin.html) service as described [here](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-web-console/extending-the-apache-felix-web-console/branding-the-web-console.html). However, I cannot get it to correctly display my logo. For testing, I added the absolute path to my `svg` in my `BrandingPlugin` like this:

```scala
import org.apache.felix.webconsole.BrandingPlugin;
import org.apache.felix.webconsole.DefaultBrandingPlugin;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;

@Component(service = BrandingPlugin.class)
public class MyBrandingPlugin implements BrandingPlugin {

    @Override
    public String getBrandName() {
        return "My company name";
    }

    @Override
    public String getProductName() {
        return "My product name";
    }

    @Override
    public String getProductURL() {
        return "https://www.my-website.com/";
    }

    @Override
    public String getProductImage() {
       return "/home/fbaierl/Repos/myproduct/Runnables/OSGi/branding/logo.svg";
    }

    @Override
    public String getVendorName() {
        return DefaultBrandingPlugin.getInstance().getVendorName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getVendorURL() {
        return DefaultBrandingPlugin.getInstance().getVendorURL();
    }

    @Override
    public String getVendorImage() {
        return DefaultBrandingPlugin.getInstance().getVendorImage();
    }

    @Override
    public String getFavIcon() {
        return DefaultBrandingPlugin.getInstance().getFavIcon();
    }

    @Override
    public String getMainStyleSheet() {
        return DefaultBrandingPlugin.getInstance().getMainStyleSheet();
    }
}
```

When I navigate to the Webconsole, I can see that `getBrandName`, `getProductName` and `getProductUrl` all work as expected. However, the image linked to in `getProductImage` is not displayed.

The resulting html looks like this:

```html
<img src="/system/console/home/fbaierl/Repos/myproduct/Runnables/OSGi/branding/logo.svg" alt="Logo">
```

Does anyone know how I can get the logo to be displayed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try prefix file: and maybe a few slashes (file:/ file:// file:///)

Comment: Maybe plugin cannot access files outside its directory, could you put image somewhere under /system/console?

Comment: Since the webconsole is only added as a dependency to my project, I cannot access it's directory structure.